# how to convert to application/pdf response to file in axios?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, axios, react-pdf

I'm getting response from the API in application/pdf response type. I need to convert this to file or base64 format to show a the file in react-pdf library.

How can I achieve this?

[image: response type]

[image: response preview]

Any help will much be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a `GET` request, you can do sth like this:

```
ar link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = yourGETurl;
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you have some real reason to use Axios for the request, you can do something like that:

```
<Document
  httpHeaders={headersObjectForAuth}
  file={{ url: sameUrlUsedByAxios }}
>
  <Page {...pageProps} />
</Document>
```

You can find more info here:

https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf#props

Comment: in my case API requires `token` to authenticate the request

Comment: You can use `httpHeaders` to specify the token, of course.